# How is boiling oil tolerated by some people?

Tags: skin, heat

There are people who can withstand exposure to extreme heat with no apparent side effects. One such person is [Kann Trichan](https://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/most-items-taken-out-of-hot-oil-with-bare-hands-in-one-minute), a Thai street vendor who dips his bare hands in hot oil. An old TV show featured another person who, as a child, was found touching a red-hot hotplate. On the show, he was filmed holding a piece of food in a deep fryer for tens of seconds, and his hand showed no visible change when it was removed, not even surface redness.

- Is science any closer to explaining the phenomenon?
- Although there are no visible ill effects, are there any that might be developing (eg. a risk of cancer due to DNA damage)?
- Why is blistering not occurring? What specifically triggers blistering, and how might it be being suppressed in these people?

Comment: For some of these cases, look into the leidenfrost effect (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leidenfrost_effect). people can literally touch molten metal for a fraction of a second and it's find simply because of the moisture in our hands providing a protective barrier when super heated.

Answer (score 1):

In a biology forum, you may be asking about a biology question by proxy, though what we'll really be getting at is that one must first correctly apply a healthy amount of scientific thinking to questions about any observations. This is more a discussion on  science and skepticism rather than a mechanism in biology, but I will humor you briefly.

> Is science any closer to explaining the phenomenon?

Why yes, in almost all of such extraordinary feats of inhuman ability, you are seeing **fraud and quackery.**

There are a great many 'phenomenal' people and feats who appear in Guinness record books and on TV programs and on YouTube videos, performing amazing and unbelievable feats. Very often these involve the presence of an 'expert' making sure everything is kosher, a science professor standing by, making sure there is no trickery and that the experiment is controlled. We've seen this plenty of times, with homeopathy demonstrations, extrasensory perception, free energy devices, wireless power transfer at a distance, conducting, storing or generating copious amounts of electricity from within their bodies (e.g. [Battery Man](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1783384/)), the list goes on.

Unfortunately, there a few things that tend to go wrong upon presentation to the audience at the very end:

1. The shows edit out much of the scrutiny or discussion of possible confounding factors. *The oil may have bubbled to indicate it's boiling, but did we measure its temperature with a thermometer?* *Was the hand covered in a heat-resistant gel or a layer of insulating water which doesn't mix with oil and provides temporary heat resistance?* *Was the hand a prosthetic?*
2. Expertise is faked by an accomplice who poses as an authority. Alternatively, an authority fails to spot the trick. You can convince many persons by virtue of a proxy; this is very human tendency that is quite easy to exploit.
3. Relatedly, with clever tricks, illusionists are often better candidates for spotting cheats than most scientists. This is [well-understood among illusionists](https://www.wired.com/2012/03/opinion-randi-magic-scientists/); 'trained folks' tend to think in certain ways and the exploitation of their expectations or predictions can proceed more easily. Analogously, visual artists may be better trained to spot fakery in videos than your average scientist (e.g. [Captain Disillusion](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCEOXxzW2vU0P-0THehuIIeg)?). This is the artful aspect of deception, and no one individual can be said to be immune from professional quacks at all times; there are myriad ways to overcome a single individual's scrutiny.

There are plenty more possible explanations, I only touch on the obvious ones. Certainly many more probable explanations than exposed human skin not reacting to boiling oil upon prolonged exposure.

Rather disappointingly, in almost every single case, performers who achieve extraordinary and inhuman feats are charlatans. A rather simple answer!